# Upvote penalty on highly downvoted posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, upvotes

Imagine this scenario: A very low quality answer gets posted, immediately followed by several downvotes (less than 5).

There are comments on the answer that indicate what's wrong and how the poster should improve/delete it.

Bam! Someone comes over and with a single pity upvote, undoes the critique being offered. The poster, now with some reputation as a reward, disappears and their post remains unmodified.

While the system still considers this post to be of poor quality (it can be voted for deletion), the message for quality is lost. The person learns that they can still earn a little reputation from bad posts, instead of working towards improving the quality of their posting.

Proposal: Upvoting a post with a score of -3 or less shuold cost a point of reputation. If a post has to be bad enough that downvoting it is worth a point of reputation, shouldn't the converse be true when said post starts off as very bad?

Comment: Alright, two people disagree already. I'd love the reasoning however. Maybe I don't understand the SO model well enough.

Comment: What if the post gets improved and isn't bad any more? Why should upvoting it still cost reputation?

Comment: I liked this idea but can't upvote since it has 3 downvotes. _I am afraid of the 1 rep_

Comment: @Keiwan - Because it's good?! Like I said, the converse still holds. Why should we pay to downvote something bad? Perhaps an edit can anull this, IDK.

Comment: @SoMeUsEr - How does snark fit the "be nice" model? Or is it different on meta (IDK, I'm kinda new to meta myself)?

Comment: @StoryTeller Using humor doesn't violate the "be nice" model.  It's not insulting anyone, or otherwise being mean.  It's making a valid point, but doing so in a more attention grabbing way than just blandly stating the point.

Comment: @Servy - Snark usually isn't good humor. It's by definition a ridiculing rhetoric.

Comment: FYI the most [upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/2427065) have 71 downvotes so the up and downvotes are decided by people and the decision vary from each person

Comment: @SoMeUsEr - Do note that I specifically referred to answer in my own question.

Comment: how the system differentiate between normal answer and VLQ

Comment: @SoMeUsEr I disagree that it's being snarky. It's just using irony.  If you don't think it was funny, that's your right, but that doesn't make it mean.

Comment: @SoMeUsEr - I would think that initial community feedback is enough. It's usually very clear cut what answers receive so many downvotes in so little time.

Comment: think the case is way to niche to spend any time and effort implementing and changing the voting system for. SO have always said they don't want to mess with voting. Let me find an example...

Comment: @StoryTeller But you're saying that upvotes should cost rep when a post has a certain negative score. That's not analogous to how downvoting an answer *always* costs rep. An arbitrary edit doesn't necessarily mean that the post was improved so why should someone before the edit pay for an upvote and someone after it not?

Comment: @Servy - It's heavy use of sarcasm meant to ridicule. Maybe not at myself personally, but still snark.

Comment: @servy I think you mistagged me [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354764/upvote-penalty-on-highly-downvoted-posts#comment502417_354764)

Comment: @Keiwan - I don't see the problem TBH. If something is good, we upvote. If something is bad we downvote. Rep cost is rarely a consideration either way. Unless for pity upvotes, that is. The freedom there seems to have a very negative effect on quality.

Comment: @Tanner - Looking forward to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller But it's not ridiculing anyone.  It's demonstrating exactly what would happen if your feature were implemented, and showing you the negative consequences that would result.  If you're personally insulted by someone explaining a situation in which your proposed feature would have negative side effects, that doesn't mean that someone else did something wrong.

Comment: @Servy - (1) I think you should stop tagging SoMeUsEr, it's bound to be annoying. (2) The validity of the argument has no bearing on the validity of the rhetoric.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think the official statement will now be posted as answer by bluefeet. She just did the tag edit

Comment: @SoMeUsEr - I certainly hope so. Because I'm not swayed yet, personally.

Comment: I don't agree with the assumption that a post with a score of -3 isn't worthy of an upvote. Posts can be edited, improved and those who downvoted aren't notified of those changes. Penalizing users for upvoting a post is not something we're going to implement.

Comment: @StoryTeller And how is making the point from the perspective of a realistic hypothetical person that would actually be adversely affected by your feature (in that situation) rather than from their own perspective invalid?  You're just *stating* that it's inappropriate.

Comment: @bluefeet - Those who downvoted also keep their own penalty for the downvotes. IDK, It seems like a motivator to keep an interest to me.

Comment: @StoryTeller What I'm trying to get at is that it would make more sense to me if you were proposing that all upvotes (at least on answers) should cost rep - instead of binding the cost to a certain score threshold. Having it coupled to the post score would add a ton of confusion to users ("Why did my upvote to this post of score -5 cost rep but my upvote on the other one at -5 didn't?" - "Because the second one was edited") and unnecessary edge cases that would all have to be implemented.

Comment: @Keiwan - And yet edits nullify "rude or abusive" flags, don't they? Perhaps an edit shouldn't mullify this. The penalty remains until an improvement is noticeable (by the only available metric, votes).

Comment: @StoryTeller A penalty for downvoting an answer is standard to make users think before doing it because it's not something that should be done lightly. If you're invested after you downvote, then that's great go back and check to see if it's been improved to upvote. But we're not going to penalize users for upvoting a post regardless of score.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yeah, I gathered that :) I may not agree yet, but I can understand.

Answer (score 5):

Mainly, if I feel a post is worth voting, **it shouldn't matter what other people felt before me**. Encouraging voting-by-example doesn't seem a nice goal to have.

The previous voters could be wrong. Or maybe they aren't, but I am still entitled to disagree with them.

On top of that; a post could be edited after is originally voted upon; and later visitors coming along need to vote on the post's quality after the edit **(which could have been triggered by the previous votes)**.

The existing score does not necessarily reflect present quality. The post being voted on might no longer be the same post the previous voters voted on.

And even more practical problems: A post gets 3 downvotes, then 6 upvotes... You'll penalize the first new votes, but not the following ones? Reimburse the rep cost?

This proposal doesn't make much sense, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's harder to appreciate something when it isn't for free. But I do feel that some upvotes don't pay any mind to quality, and this can sway people to bear quality in mind.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to encourage "voting-by-example". The penalty for downvotes already goes towards stopping any bandwagons. This is about counter-productive upvoting.

Comment: @storyteller That's your opinion though. Voting is completely up to the users. You don't get to dictate their votes regardless of how they cast them.

Comment: @SandPiper I would counter that the same applies to downvotes, and yet an attempt at regulation already exists there.